# creating a sql view

Tags: sql, data-analysis, sql-view

how can i create a sql view that collects " data that only exists in all 8 table" ?
for example i want to retrieve/ create a view that shows lists of countries that exists in all tables.

Comment: A well-crafted join can be assembled into a view for the purpose you want. Please add a few rows of sample data (2 or 3 tables will suffice) and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your data set it's hard to know exactly what to do.

So you have 8 tables....   And you want a list of countries.

You could do something like this.  Note I would consider union all if you want to look for counts etc, but if you are just looking for a distinct list of countries you could do this and union would make your list distinct between each table.

```
CREATE VIEW vwCOUNTRYLIST
AS
SELECT Country from Table1
UNION
SELECT Country from Table2
UNION
SELECT Country from Table3
UNION
SELECT Country from Table4
UNION
SELECT Country from Table5
UNION
SELECT Country from Table6
UNION
SELECT Country from Table7
UNION
SELECT Country from Table8
```

Comment: and now how do i  delete all countries information that don’t exist in the vw_countries

Comment: I would create another question and add some sample data that is layed out in your tables so we can assist better.   I'm not sure I understand what you mean deleting country data that doesn't exist.  Do you have another table with countries that aren't in these 8 tables?

Comment: i know, i was going to create anolther question but i have to wait 90 min,
 but im working on a project and i have  8 tables, and this is the list
- Create a view of all the distinct countries that exist in all tables. Call it vw_Countries
- From each tables, delete all countries information that don’t exist in the vw_countries
- Get the range of the years common to all the tables --- this needs more work

Comment: @solo If you create the view as a union of all possible countries across 8 tables, how can there be any countries that don't exist in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to better define your question, it is very generic, to create a view you simply prepend this code to the statement you want to turn into a view

```
CREATE VIEW vwMYViewName
AS
```

For the second part of your question, with this you can get only the country names that are in the 8 tables

```
CREATE VIEW vwCOUNTRYSONALLTABLES
AS
SELECT Country
FROM ( SELECT Country FROM Tbl1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Country FROM Tbl8
    ) DtAllCountrys
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(Country) = 8
```

Comment: This is the correct answer after reviewing your code it makes sense what the original ask was.  My apologies I thought you were just looking for an all inclusive list of countries.  Now it makes more sense why you want to delete them.  PS Upvoted this solution

Comment: `union` will give distinct results if you take out the `all`.

Comment: It is important to union all, otherwise there would be no way to meet the condition that it exists in the 8 tables